# Scope.attribute available but scope.attribute.variable undefined in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-resource

I'm trying some angularJS development, but I'm facing a issue that I do not understand at all.

I try to format a JSON into a specific table with many rules. For now my JSON look like:

```
{
    "id":"test",
    "title":"Test Sample",
    "description":"Test Sample Description"
}
```

it is loaded into `list`:

```
angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource'])
   .factory('MyData', ['$resource',
       function($resource){
        return $resource('/rest/data', {}, {
            getSample: {method:'GET', url:'/data/sample.json', isArray:false}               
        });
       }
    ]);

angular.module('myControllers', ['myServices'])
    .controller('DataController', ['$scope', 'MyData',
        function($scope, MyData){
            $scope.list = MyData.getSample(); //retrive a simple JSON
        }
    ]);
```

then I try to rearrange data with :

```
<div id="list" data-ng-controller="DataController">   
    <div data-table="view" data-list="list"></div>
</div>
```

and for now a simple directive:

```
angular.module('myDirectives', [])
   .directives('table', function($timeout){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: { list : '='},
            link: function(scope,$element, attrs){
                console.log(scope);
                console.log(scope.list);
                console.log(scope.list.title);
            }
        };
    });
```

but here what happen in `console.log()` :
I have `scope` :

```
$$asyncQueue: Array[0]
$$childHead: null
$$childTail: null
$$destroyed: false
$$isolateBindings: Object
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: null
$$phase: null
$$postDigestQueue: Array[0]
$$prevSibling: null
$$watchers: Array[1]
$id: "007"
$parent: a
$root: h
list: Resource
this: h
__proto__: h
```

I have `scope.list` (marked as `Resource`):

```
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
description: "Test Sample Description"
id: "test"
title: "Test Sample"
__proto__: Resource
```

but `scope.list.title` is marked as `undefined`.

My search lead to some attribute which may not have been set at link, but why the `scope.list` is still available and not its property ?

I've also tried to set the `scope` to `true` into `table` directive, but nothing better happen

I'm about to make a complexe table so I have to apply very specific rules within this div and table. I can't do it simply with some `ng-If`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.list` is a promise.  In your case the promise has already been resolved, thus the `$resolved: true`.  But it's a promise none the less.

From the [ngResource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#usage_returns):

> $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created
>   this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or
>   collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy
>   to use in resolve section of $routeProvider.when() to defer view
>   rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.

So in Angular 1.2+ you want to do something like this where you provide a callback using `then` on the `$promise` attribute of the promise. Once the promise is resolved the callback will then be called with the results (in your case since the promise is already resolved the callback will execute immediately).

```
link: function(scope,$element, attrs){
         scope.list.$promise.then(function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            console.log("title ",results.title);
         });
      }
```

Here's a [working demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKqB6/1/) that uses $httpbackend to simulate your server's response.

Comment: Simply perfect answer, thank you for pointing me into the proper documentation paragraph. I was absolutly not aware about those $promise and $resolved properties